# Writing a query for alternative column names as mentioned below eg

Tags: sql, if-statement, null, conditional-statements

The query for, If the address is missing, displays the email id. If both address and email are missing then display ‘NA’. Give an alias name as CONTACT_DETAILS. Considering the above-mentioned example, please help with writing the query.

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN 1 THEN ifnull(address,email_id)  
       WHEN 2 THEN ifnull(email_id,'NA')
  END
as contact_details
FROM customers;
```

The query which i tried

Comment: The COALESCE() function returns the first non-null value in a list. So you can use it to display email_id if Address is null and 'NA' if both are null.

Would you try 
SELECT COALESCE(address, email_id, 'NA') AS contact_details 
FROM customers

Comment: What is `WHEN 1`?  That is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(address,email_id, 'NA') contact_details FROM customers;
```

From Documentation:

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **COALESCE** function. Your query would be something like this

```
SELECT COALESCE(address, email_id, 'NA') as contact_details
FROM customers;
```

As far i have checked its available in oracle and mysql.
Use these links for reference:

1. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-coalesce-function/
2. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions023.htm#i1001341